# Error 424 Object required while replicating the grouping style of rows from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform which has a Listbox (Listbox1) which list down all the worksheets name present in the workbook. I have an OptionBox (OptionBox1).
I have set the `OptionBox1. value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`

So I basically want whatever sheet I select from my listbox the grouping rows format of that sheet should be replicated in my activesheet.

I am getting error 424 in the following line :

```
lastrow = Me.ListBox1.List(i).UsedRange.Row + Me.ListBox1.List(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
```

Please find below my code:

```
Dim sh As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Me.OptionButton1.Value = ws    

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
 lastrow = Me.ListBox1.List(i).UsedRange.Row + Me.ListBox1.List(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

  For j = Me.ListBox1.List(i).UsedRange.Row To lastrow
  ws.Rows(j).OutlineLevel = Me.ListBox1.List(i).Rows(j).OutlineLevel
  Next

  End If
   Next
  End If   


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'for each loop the add visible sheets
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

'add sheets to the listbox

Me.ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name

Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Me.ListBox1.List(i)` is the **name** of your worksheet, you need to use `Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i)).UsedRange` rather than `Me.ListBox1.List(i).UsedRange`.

You probably need to change your code to:

```
Dim sh As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Me.OptionButton1.Value = ws.Name  ' Set the value to the NAME of the worksheet   

        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
                With Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.List(i))
                    lastrow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

                    For j = .UsedRange.Row To lastrow
                        ws.Rows(j).OutlineLevel = .Rows(j).OutlineLevel
                    Next
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If   

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'for each loop the add visible sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        'add sheets to the listbox
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Its working thank you. Now I will try to apply it in all the sheets in case I am stuck will raise another question.